# Add percent (per row) column to a R data.frame the elegant way

Tags: r

I want to have the percent values as a column in a `data.frame`. The example code works. But **the question** is if this is the *correct* and *elegant R-way* to do this?

```
> df <- data.frame(addmargins(table(mtcars$gear, useNA="always")))
> df
  Var1 Freq
1    3   15
2    4   12
3    5    5
4 <NA>    0
5  Sum   32

> df$percent <- mapply(function(x) {100 / length(mtcars$gear) * x}, df$Freq)
> df
  Var1 Freq percent
1    3   15  46.875
2    4   12  37.500
3    5    5  15.625
4 <NA>    0   0.000
5  Sum   32 100.000
```

For me there is no need to restrict this question to `data.frame`.

Comment: If your data frame already has the two columns which are used to find the percentage, why don't you just directly take a ratio (maybe I am missing something here)?

Comment: In that example the sum are all cars (`n=32`) in `mtcars`. How much (in `%`) of them have 3 (or 4 or 5) gears.

Comment: `c(with(head(df, -1), Freq / sum(Freq) * 100), 100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding margins is bad practice as you are mixing data with summaries.

```
df <- data.frame(table(mtcars$gear, useNA="always"))
df$pct <-df$Freq/sum(df$Freq)*100
df
#>   Var1 Freq    pct
#> 1    3   15 46.875
#> 2    4   12 37.500
#> 3    5    5 15.625
#> 4 <NA>    0  0.000
```

Or in idiomatic `dplyr` code (no need to bother with `table`):

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(Freq=n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent=Freq/sum(Freq)*100)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    gear  Freq percent
#>   <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
#> 1     3    15    46.9
#> 2     4    12    37.5
#> 3     5     5    15.6
```

Note that there's no need to `ungroup` after summarize, as you only have one grouping variable and summarize is stripping exactly one layer of grouping

Answer (score 1):

I'd advocate for a `dplyr::mutate` based solution for clarity:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(percent = (Freq/nrow(mtcars)) * 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use the `table` function in **base R** for this task (using it from the start):

```
df <- data.frame(
  "g" = names(table(mtcars$gear)), 
  "f" = as.numeric(table(mtcars$gear)), 
  "p" = as.numeric(100 * (table(mtcars$gear)/length(mtcars$gear)))
)
```

This is the result:

```
> df
  g  f      p
1 3 15 46.875
2 4 12 37.500
3 5  5 15.625
```

Alternatively adding the percent after the creation of the data.frame for a shorter bit of code:

```
df <- data.frame(table(mtcars$gear))
df$p <- 100 * (df[,'Freq'] / sum(df[,'Freq']))
```

Giving:

```
> df
  Var1 Freq      p
1    3   15 46.875
2    4   12 37.500
3    5    5 15.625
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) prop.table** `prop.table` can be useful here.  We use `ave` to apply it separately to the data and summary rows.

```
transform(df, Percent = 100 * ave(Freq, Var1 == "Sum", FUN = prop.table))
```

giving:

```
  Var1 Freq Percent
1    3   15  46.875
2    4   12  37.500
3    5    5  15.625
4 <NA>    0   0.000
5  Sum   32 100.000
```

**2) tables package** If the purpose of this is to display the indicated table then the tables package is nice.  The terms on the LHS of the formula refer to the rows and on the RHS refer to the columns.

```
library(tables)

gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
tab <- tabular(gear + 1 ~ (n=1) + Percent())
```

giving:

```
> tab
gear n  Percent
 3    15  46.88 
 4    12  37.50 
 5     5  15.62 
 All  32 100.00
```

HTML and LaTeX output can now be produced using `html(tab)` and `latex(tab)` .

This approach is more geared toward display but if you really wanted to extract out the data it could be done like this:

```
m <- as.matrix(tab, format = as.numeric)
dimnames(m) <- list(attr(tab, "rowLabels"), attr(tab, "colLabels"))
```